# Re-size iFrame that actively changes its height

Tags: javascript, c#, html, iframe

The task was to re-size an embedded iFrame, that would actively change its content without reloading itself or the parent, therefore pretty much all the available answers around wouldn't work, as they suggest to

```
<iframe src="url" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>
```

use `onLoad` to invoke a Re-size function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue on my parent page I have the following:
index.aspx

```
<div>
 <script>
  function resizeIframe(height) {
    document.getElementById('frameUpload').height = height;
   }
  </script>
<iframe id="iframe" src="/child/page.aspx"  marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And inside my page.aspx's body I have:

```
<body  onChange="CallThisToResize();">
```

Then inside the body i have the following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallThisToResize() {
    var body = document.body,
html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
                   html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    parent.resizeIframe(height);
}
```

What this does is, everytime the body changes, it gets the new height, sends it to the parent, and then the iframe height is re-sized accordingly.